# Getting/setting style of element when style is defined in id/class css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I might be missing something easy here, but I'm trying to get/set the background color of a div, but only if the background color is already set (whether it be from class/id, or style attribute, etc.).

I've tried using `.style.backgroundColor`, but all it returns is an empty string (I think because the attribute is defined in the class/id, not the element style itself). [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o0v268fz/2/) to show what I mean.

I can't use jQuery, and I also can't just select the attribute of the class/id itself because I'm doing this with a large collection of (potentially unrelated) elements.

In the end, the goal is to have something like this:

```
var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
    if (allElements[i].style.backgroundColor != '') {
        allElements[i].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: To be honest, this is a backwards way of approaching the situation. The color is not a state, the color is just the style applied to a state. Therefore, you should set the color using a class that indicates the state (eg `.active, .error` etc), then check if that particular class is applied to the element. If you think about it, what you probably want to know is whether the element has a specific state. The specific color isn't important; it's just a style for that state and you really shouldn't tie that into your logic.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. However, I don't really have the option to set any classes :\ this is part of a mini-javascript library that can't use any dependencies and should be able to run on any page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to use `getComputedStyle()` function: https://jsfiddle.net/rk53agzj/.

JS:

```
var byId = document.getElementById.bind(document);
byId("ending").innerText = "The color is " + getComputedStyle(byId("intro")).backgroundColor + ".";
```

Comment: The `getComputedStyle` is for IE 9 and up only.

Comment: @AlexanderDixon Microsoft discontinued support for XP (thus, IE8) in April 2014 - well over a year ago. Unless you're developing some kind of legacy app, < IE8 support should be considered irrelevant and isn't worth mentioning. It's like posting a review about a new car saying "it doesn't work on leaded petrol". Irrelevant, because we don't sell leaded petrol any more.

Comment: If early IE support is critical for OP, then he can just use `getComputedStyle` polyfill.  There are plenty of implementation out there and here's one of them: https://github.com/jonathantneal/Polyfills-for-IE8/blob/master/getComputedStyle.js.